# mapping functions in dict

Tags: python

I want to run python functions from linux command prompt. So, I define a functions and dictionary of mappings from linux inputs to the functions to be exectured. So,eg.

```
def help():
    print(...)

def dostuff():
    do sth

functions ={
    'help': help()'
    ''dostuff' : dostuff()
    }

def parsecommand():
    return functions[sys.argv]

if __name__='__main__':
    parsecommand()
```

When I now run a function from Linux, [python filename.py] help the problem now is that python runs through all the functions in the dictionary and executes them when building the dictionary. How can I avoid this?
Or what would be a better way to structure this?

Answer (score 3):

Change your dict like so:

```
functions = {
    'help': help,
    'dostuff' : dostuff
    }
```

This will allow you to call the functions in the following manner:

```
functions[sys.argv[1]]()
```

Answer (score 2):

Remove the `()` next to the function names in the dictionary.

```
functions ={
  'help': help
  'dostuff' : dostuff
}
```

You'd than be able  to run the functions like so:

```
return functions[sys.argv[1]]()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
functions = {
    'help': help,
    'dostuff': dostuff
}

def parsecommand():
    return functions[sys.argv]()
```